# What does MACHINEOVERRIDES flag mean?

Tags: yocto

I am currently writing a machine configuration file and I bumped ahead the `MACHINEOVERRIDES` flag, which I don't understand. It is for example used [here](https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/blob/master/conf/machine/raspberrypi3-64.conf). [In the documentation](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-OVERRIDES), only override is precised, no mention of MACHINEOVERRIDE.

Would you know where to find more information about it or how to see the impact checking the build environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual does describe MACHINEOVERRIDES:  http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-MACHINEOVERRIDES .

The impact in build environment is that recipes can now do things conditionally only on the builds for that specific machine:

```
SRC_URI_append_raspberrypi3 = "file://patch_file_needed_only_on_rpi3.patch"
```

See the [Bluez bbappend](https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi/blob/master/recipes-connectivity/bluez5/bluez5_%25.bbappend) in the same repo for multiple examples of this.

Comment: I wonder how I missed it. Even tho, thanks for the explanation